# Receiving NULL when sending function output to ui.R in server.R

Tags: r

My server.R code:

```
rf <- randomForest(mpg ~., data=my_data)

shinyServer( function(input, output) {

    df_list <- reactive ({ c(as.numeric(input$inputA), as.numeric(input$inputB), as.numeric(input$inputC), as.numeric(input$inputD)) })

    df <- reactive ({ as.data.frame(df_list) })  

    reactive ({ colnames(df) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D") })

    prediction <- reactive({ predict(rf, df) })

    result <- reactive({as.numeric(prediction)})

    output$predictE <- reactive ({result})

    })
```

My ui.R code:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar (
    headerPanel("Prediction"),
    sidebarPanel(
        numericInput(inputId="inputA", label = "", value = 1.0),
        numericInput(inputId="inputB", label = "", value = 1.0),
        numericInput(inputId="inputC", label = "", value = 1.0),
        numericInput(inputId="inputD", label = "", value= 1.0),
        submitButton("Submit")

      ),
    mainPanel(
      p('Output'),
      textOutput('predictE')
    )  
    ) )
```

I'm trying to take some values from ui.R and use them to generate a prediction based on an RF model, and send the output back.

I can send input$inputA back to ui.R with no problem, as I tested output$predictE <- reactive ({input$inputA}). But if I generate a prediction using my RF model I receive a NULL.

If I perform the steps in the R command-line inside the shinyServer function, the prediction yields a result as expected.

Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: can you post your `ui.R` code as well, and `dput` some of the data?

Comment: try either `output$predictE <- renderPrint({result()})` or `output$predictE <- renderText({result()})`

Comment: Thanks Mark - I tried both of these, but R throws a cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double' error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that you didn't really grasp what a `reactive` is. I suggest you to follow a [tutorial](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/). However, here seems that you don't need any reactive, while you need your output to be rendered in some way. Try this:

```
rf <- randomForest(mpg ~., data=my_data)
shinyServer( function(input, output) {

output$predictE <- renderText({
  df_list <-c(as.numeric(input$inputA), as.numeric(input$inputB), as.numeric(input$inputC), as.numeric(input$inputD))
  df <- as.data.frame(df_list) 
  colnames(df) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
  prediction <- predict(rf, df)
  result <- as.numeric(prediction)
  result
})
})
```

Comment: Ah, thank you!  I did need to transpose the df which I had forgot to do.